# Request failed with status 400 due to invalid cookie domain: Cookie 'domain' mismatch

Tags: webdriver-io, npm-scripts

I am using webdriver io and getting below error.
webdriver: Request failed with status 400 due to invalid cookie domain: invalid cookie domain: Cookie 'domain' mismatch

I have removed node modules and restarted system ,installled again .Still facing issue.These step worked for me earlier but not now.Below are the versions of packages I am using.Chrome version on my system is 91.0.4472.114

── @babel/cli@7.12.10
├── @babel/core@7.12.10
├── @babel/preset-env@7.12.11
├── @babel/register@7.12.10
├── @wdio/allure-reporter@7.7.3
├── @wdio/cli@7.7.4
├── @wdio/devtools-service@7.7.4
├── @wdio/jasmine-framework@7.7.3
├── @wdio/local-runner@7.7.4
├── @wdio/selenium-standalone-service@7.7.4
├── @wdio/spec-reporter@7.7.3
├── @wdio/sync@7.7.4
├── allure-commandline@2.13.8
├── atob@2.1.2
├── eslint-plugin-import@2.22.1
├── eslint@5.16.0
├── fs-extra@7.0.1
├── jasmine-allure-reporter@1.0.2
├── jasmine-expect@4.0.3
├── jasmine@3.7.0
├── lodash@4.17.21
├── prettier@1.18.2
├── randomstring@1.1.5
├── superagent@5.3.1
├── wd@1.13.0
├── wdio-docker-service@2.4.0
├── wdio-timeline-reporter@5.1.4
└── webdriverio@6.12.1

Comment: please add a reproducible example

Comment: @wdio/selenium-standalone-service version 7.7.4,
Chrome version installed on Mac:91.0.4472.114,
Added a cookie to pass cloudfare access.

Comment: When I uninstalled selenium-standalone-service,I see cookie is setting up correctly without any issue though test are not running as selenium standalone service is not there.
Is it something to do with the version of selenium standalone and chrome browser?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Would you be able to add more details? like what are you trying to do and how is your configuration file looks like.

Comment: Our UI automation code is on Webdriver IO and I am facing issue which is specific to my machine.
For hitting the base urls, we need to set cookie and then run tests.I am getting below error when setting cookie(Which was working earlier).
ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 400 due to invalid cookie domain: invalid cookie domain: Cookie 'domain' mismatch
Same code works for other people in my team.Even package.json is also same as others.
Selenium-standalone service version: 7.7.4
Chrome version on my Mac:91.0.4472.101

Comment: I have restarted my system->deleted node modules->installed it.